# Spring data jpa , relationship

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem in spring data jpa. I have two tables 1.Reservation 2.Cottage my relationshio is One reservation can have many cottage but i want my foriegn key will be put in reservation. Is that possible? If yes what is the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

This is `one to many` relationship.
You can represent this cottage in reservation entity as below

```java
.....

 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cottage", fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Cottage> cottage;

....
```

in the Reservation entity class.
For more, please refer the below [link](https://attacomsian.com/blog/spring-data-jpa-one-to-many-mapping)